# Möbius transformation that carries the real axis to the unit circle

Tags: complex-analysis

It is known that any (invertible) Möbius transformation carries lines and circles in the complex plane into lines and circles. Which Möbius transformations
$$
T(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}
$$
carries the real axis into the unit circle? More generally, which Möbius transformations carry lines into circles? Thanks.

Comment: That is seldom a linear transformation. It is a Möbius transformation.

Comment: One way to find such transformations is to use the method [described here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation#Specifying_a_transformation_by_three_points) with the $z_j$ on the real line and the $w_j$ on the unit circle.

Comment: Even though they are not linear, Möbius transformations are often referred to as 'linear fractional transformations' or even as 'linear transformations'. Ahlfors uses this nomencalture in his complex analysis book

Comment: Does this help you?https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2931699/mobius-transformation-maps-the-real-axis-to-the-unit-circle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select any $3$ distinct points $z_1,z_2,z_3$ on the unit circle. We note that the transformation
$$
S(z) = \frac{(z - z_1)(z_2 - z_3)}{(z - z_3)(z_2 - z_1)} = \frac{(z_2 - z_3)z + z_1(z_3 - z_2)}{(z_2 - z_1)z + z_3(z_2 - z_1)}
$$
maps $z_1,z_2,z_3$ to $0,1,\infty$.  It follows that the inverse transformation
$$
T(z) = S^{-1}(z) = \frac{z_{3}(z_2 - z_1)\,z + z_1(z_2 - z_3)}{(z_1 - z_2)\,z + (z_2 - z_3)}
$$
maps $0,1,\infty$ to the unit circle. It is clear that selecting distinct $z_1,z_2,z_3$ leads to distinct transformations. Moreover, because any bilinear transformation sends the points $0,1,\infty$ *somewhere*, we can conclude that every bilinear transformation that takes $\Bbb R$ to the unit circle has the above form for some choice of $z_1,z_2,z_3$ on the unit circle.  In other words, the above defines a one-to-one correspondence between the maps we want and $\Bbb T^3$.

One particularly "nice" example of such a transformation is
$$
f(z) = \frac{z + i}{z - i},
$$
which corresponds to selecting $z_1 = -1,z_2 = i, z_3 = 1$. Indeed, substituting these $z_j$ into the above yields
$$
\frac{1(i-(-1))z + (-1)(i-1)}{(-1 - i)z + (i - 1)} = 
\frac{-(1 + i)z + (1-i)}{-(1 + i)z - (1 - i)}\\
= \frac{-(1 + i)z + (1-i)}{-(1 + i)z - (1 - i)} \cdot \frac {-(1-i)}{-(1-i)}
\\ = \frac{2z + 2i}{2z - 2i} = \frac{z + i}{z - i}.
$$